# Selenium webdriver application for testing an other ERP web application

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

We have an ERP web application built in Spring mvc.

Until now were testing our ERP application manually.

Now we need to do automatic testing. For that, we have decided to use selenium webdriver. This means that we need to create a Selenium webdriver application to automatically test our ERP web application.

But I am not sure which type of Selenium webdriver application it should be. Should it be web application or desktop application? And how can we run it?

I have tried but not able to find answer.

Comment: Please let us know, which tutorials and introductions to Selenium you already read. Am I right that you haven't started implementing yet?

Comment: Peter Wippermann Sir, I viewed only web driver sample source code from some sources. I have not yet started implementing. No idea which type of application it should be.

Comment: Posting another answer here has been deactived atm, so I leave a short comment: You should write your automated tests as unit tests (JUnit, TestNG). Start a whole new project (Maven, Gradle, "plain Java") and implement your tests there. You can execute your tests manually ("mvn test") or integrate your test project in your Continuous Integration build and have it run there automatically. Eitherway, you don't write a classic application - neither web, nor desktop - but only unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `Maven or gradle` project instead of normal Java project.The advantages over normal Java project are,

1. Maven project layout structure
     It will help you to manage your code easily.When application growth you have to add `webApp` component to see the automated test results and etc...
2. Project Modularization
     You can add sub modules in maven.In your case you can maintain web driver binary project for separately to get the browser drivers.eg:chrome driver,Fire fox driver.
3. Dependency Management and Project Lifecycle
    you can maintain dependency required in your project very easily instead of adding jars into your lib manually.Also you can easily integrate with one of the `version control system`eg:GIT to share code among  developers and maintain a [build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for production,testing,etc... like vise.
4. Easily integrate with [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) and other tools when you needed.

[Here](http://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html) is some tutorial for startup with selenium with Maven and Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks gihan sir. One more thing. It should be a web application or desktop application?

Comment: it should be a maven project follow the above tutorial and later on if you want you can add the `webApp` component into your project.The best practice is maintain two maven project for `test scripting` and `java selenium code(Your own API wraped selenium functionalities)` initializing web driver and so on.Then you will have code re usability.Finally add your api into your test script project as dependency and do the scripting.When application growth also think about the page object pattern.

Comment: please accept the answer if you got what you needed.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer gets any upvotes and no, it shouldn't be the accepted answer. @gihan , you're mixing up different things here. "Java Project" and "Maven Project" sound like Eclipse specific ways to organise and visualise your code and dependencies. That has nothing to do with the application's type which might be "Desktop", "Web" or "Native mobile" (to simplify things...).

Comment: @PeterWippermann The orginal post was different than the edited one.My answer was  for the original post.

Comment: You're right, before editing this thread the OP explicitly asked for Maven.
Nonetheless, Maven is not the key technology to get a Selenium test project running. If your answer puts a focus on Maven's advantages, you distract the OP from the actual challenges he has to solve. The tutorial you linked contains quite a lot of information. Is Guru99 your website? However, the tutorial describes how to implement a Unit test that controls Selenium. I think that's the important essence.

Comment: @PeterWippermann the OP was asking about what project structure should chosen to his project between java or maven. so i clearly pointed out what were the odds.and i agree with u the project structure wont matter to write a selenium code.but when it comes to enterprise level it not about only coding it contains some other stuff also to think about.Guru99 is not belong to me.